# Параллельное выполнение задач PHP

Tags: php, sql, linux, cron

Есть файл который запускается каждые N минут. Когда запускается этот файл там происходит примерно следующее:

1. Выводиться список групп из MySQL.
2. Начинает обновлять информацию о группах делая запрос в API VK.
3. Получает нужную информацию и записывает их в MySQL.

Если делать последовательно, получается критическое время ожидания. Важно что бы 100 групп выполнялись не более 1 минуты. Если сделать эту задачу не последовательно а параллельно, в теории это будет занимать примерное 10 секунд и даже меньше. Вопрос уже будет состоят в мощности сервера, но это не проблема.

Можно конечно создать десятки файлов и поставить их в КРОН задачу. Но мне кажется есть куда элегантнее решение да и конце в концов правильное.

Comment: Решение зависит от точно известной задачи. По вашему описанию ничего конкретного предложить не возможно. Чаще всего при работе с SQL подобные задачи решаются созданием одного запроса, который обрабатывает сразу все группы. Любая работа с SQL-БД мелкими запросами, обрабатывающими небольшие части данных обычно очень медленна. Но разумеется бывают и исключения, когда один запрос оказыватся хуже или по каким то причинам вообще невозможен и вот тогда надо уже искать другие решения. При этом не забывая, что если операции сильно грузят диск то их параллельное выполнение медленнее последовательного.

Comment: @Mike Обновил информацию вопроса.

Comment: Ну вот, оказывается дело упирается на в расчеты и не в БД, а в сетевые запросы. Тогда надо смотреть в сторону асинхронной работы с сетью, что бы скрипт не простаивал, пока ждет ответ от сервера. Если вам конечно VK позволит отправлять так много запросов одновременно. Вот там в ответе предлагают curl_multi, это как раз асинхронный механизм

Comment: @Mike Тогда такой вопрос. Например есть файл с 2 функциями. Как сделать так что бы они запустились одновременно и начали выполняться параллельно друг другу?

Comment: Так как это функции, которые обе используют процессор, то только в отдельных потоках их запускать. https://habr.com/post/300952/ или использовать вообще отдельный процесс с помощью fork. Если у вас не сложные вычисления требующие процессор все таки рекомендую смотреть в сторону асинхронности, а не мультизадачности

Comment: @Mike Вы правы, изначально я и хотел сказать что мне нужно асинхронное выполнение задачи. Как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контексте выполнения скрипта PHP изначально однопоточный. Есть разные ухищрения по распараллеливанию, но они по своему духу близки расставлению костылей.

Варианты есть такие:

1. Использовать другой язык. Гапример Go - он очень хорош в плане многопоточности. Sad but true.
2. Оптимизировать работу скрипта. 10-20 секунд на обработку 5 сущностей - это, в общем случае, очень долго. Но тут надо знать вашу специфику.
3. Запускать несколько процессов демонов, которые будут крутиться в бесконечном цикле и читать задания из очереди (например RabbitMQ, Redis и т.д.)
4. То же, что и 3, но пушить задания в воркеры из мастер-процесса оркестратора.

**UPD** в связи с обновлением вопроса

Скорее всего узким местом у вас является запрос к API VK. В этом случае можно использовать [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/curl_multi_init), для распараллеливания запросов.

Comment: Обновил информацию вопроса.

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос. Например есть файл с 2 функциями. Как сделать так что бы они запустились одновременно и начали выполняться параллельно друг другу?

Comment: @ДмитрийМовсесян в рамках одного скрипта - никак. Можно воспользоваться расширением `pthreads` (http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pthreads.php) для запуска дочерних процессов, которым передать выполнение задачи, но это чревато и не сказать, чтоб просто

Answer (score 0):

Можешь попробовать расширение pthreads или multicurl (обрати внимание на библиотеку http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). Может быть тебе подойдет этот вариант http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php. 
Как я понял, список групп можно запросить один раз и потом, уже исходя из содержимого списка, необходимо выполнять запросы ко внешнему API.