# Запуск команды flock из php через linux

Tags: php, linux, flock

Пытаюсь запустить команду для Linux (см.ниже.) через php. Она отрабатывает через консоль linux, но не через php.
Т.е. идея скрипта в том. Чтобы запустить обработку данных в фоновом режиме.

Ниже отображено упрощенное вырождение. Скрипт спотыкается на первой двойной ковычке ("). $retval - пустой массив. А $returnInfo выводит 66. Это как я думаю число обработанных символов.

```
exec('flock -xn /tmp/python/python.flock -c "python /billing/py/python.py"', $retval, $returnInfo);
```

Я пробовал system, shell_exec и shell. Но все четно.
Я понимаю что есть внутренняя функция у php flock(). Но я не могу ей воспользоваться, так как скрипт должен запустить обработку и завершить работу. (вывести сообщение пользователю, что данные скоро будут обработаны )

Возможно кто нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей. Помогите пожалуйста.

P.S. Я смотрел статью [Параллельное выполнение задач PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925660/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87-php) Но там все общее. А мне просто надо отладить код. Может быть запрос надо как-то хитро экранировать?

Всем спасибо за комментарии.
Решение

```
exec('flock -xn /tmp/python/python.flock -c `python /billing/py/python.py`', $retval, $returnInfo);
```

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1386330/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-linux-%d0%b8%d0%b7-php)

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Прочитайте про утилиту `screen` в `unix-like` системах